# Adding a price range instead of a single price to a product with Open Graph

Tags: seo, ecommerce, structured-data, open-graph-protocol

The Facebook Open Graph prescribes that price of products can be specified this way:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# product: http://ogp.me/ns/product#">
    ...
    <meta property="og:title" content="----PRODUCT TITLE----" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="----PRODUCT DESCRIPTION----" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="product" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://-----PRODUCT_URL----" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://-----PRODUCT_IMAGE_URL----" />
    <meta property="product:price:amount" content="----PRICE----" /> 
    <meta property="product:price:currency" content="USD" />
    ...
</head>
```

which includes the price of the product.

However, the product I am trying to show has a price range instead of single price. Is it possible to have a price range with Open Graph?
If not, does anyone know any workaround for it?

Comment: [Cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41621149/1591669)